# Determining File Type from Content URI without Extension

Tags: android, uri, mime-types

I am currently working with content URIs in my Android application, and I need a reliable way to determine the file type of a given URI. The challenge is that these URIs do not have any file extensions associated with them. For instance, I would like to identify if the URI corresponds to a CSS file, JSON file, or any other specific file type.

Here's the code I'm using to retrieve the MIME type:

```java
ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
String mimeType = null;
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
try {
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int mimeTypeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE);
        if (mimeTypeColumnIndex != -1) {
            mimeType = cursor.getString(mimeTypeColumnIndex);
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

If the MIME type is null or equals "application/force-download", I'm falling back to another method called detectMimeTypeUsingTika1, which utilizes the Apache Tika library to detect the MIME type based on the URI's content. However, I have noticed that this method consistently returns "text/plain" for CSS, JS, and JSON files as well.

Here's the code for detectMimeTypeUsingTika1:

```java
public static String detectMimeTypeUsingTika1(Uri uri, ContentResolver contentResolver) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
        Tika tika = new Tika();
        return tika.detect(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is there a more accurate approach or any improvements to my existing code that would allow me to correctly identify the file type based on the content URI?

Currently, the detectMimeTypeUsingTika1 method consistently returns "text/plain" for CSS, JS, and JSON files. I want to be able to differentiate between these file types and others without relying solely on the file extensions.

Comment: "Here's the code I'm using to retrieve the MIME type" -- have you considered calling `getType()` on the `ContentResolver`?

Comment: It returns text/plain for css and js, and json because that's what they are.  The app may not know anymore than that itself.  If you really need to more than the MIME type, you'll have to open it and inspect the contents.

Comment: how can i see in java from the content the mime type?

Answer (score -1):

To determine the file type of a content URI in your Android application, you can improve the accuracy of your code by extracting the file extension from the display name of the file. Here's a shorter and simpler version of the code:

```java
String type = null;
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String fileName = cursor.getString(0);
    type = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
}
```

This code snippet retrieves the display name of the file from the cursor and then uses substring to extract the file extension. By doing so, you can accurately identify the file type without relying solely on the file extensions.

Comment: A few of your answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: it is my answer, since i am not so good in writing english i asked ai to help me write it, but the answer is not from ui

Comment: sorry I am bad at writing English so I asked the AI to fix my spelling mistakes if you believe that this answer was against the terms and conditions of Stackoverflow please feel free to downvote it

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I'm supportive of using AI for grammar assistance, personally.  Thanks for the clarification!